# admin-ajax.php returns "No Script Kiddies!" sometimes

Tags: plugin-development, ajax, query-posts

I have a custom plugin which requests for next set of posts in the given category and displays them in a specific way. 
The ajax call to admin-ajax.php is returning "No Script Kiddies!" thought many times.

It works intermittently and intermittently it doesn't work. The call works fine on our beta site which has the same plugin, same code.

Would appreciate any pointers.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: AjaxURL,
            data: {
                'ID': value,
                'catid': categoryid,
                'markup_type': markup_type,
                'order_next_posts': order_next_posts,
                'post_link_target': post_link_target,
                'posts_featured_size': posts_featured_size,
                '_wpnonce': bis_frontend_js_params.bbscroll_ajax_nonce,
                'action': 'bis_populate_posts'
            }
```

Here is the excerpt from the php code, trying to get post html and later append in order to implement infinite scrolling of articles.

```
function bis_populate_posts(){
       if ( !empty( $_POST ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'bis-ajax-nonce' ) ) {
            if (!isset($_POST['ID']))
              die();

          $post_id      = sanitize_text_field($_POST['ID']);
          $in_same_term = sanitize_text_field($_POST['catid']);
          $nextpoststype = sanitize_text_field($_POST['order_next_posts']);

          $post_link_target = (isset($_POST['post_link_target'])?sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_link_target']):'_self');
          $posts_featured_size = (isset($_POST['posts_featured_size'])?sanitize_text_field($_POST['posts_featured_size']):'large');

          $post_id      = $this->get_previous_post_id( $post_id, $in_same_term , $nextpoststype );
          if($post_id){
              $args     = array(
                'p'     =>  $post_id
                );
          $query = new WP_Query($args);
          $postCounter = 0;
          while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            global $post;?>

      <div class="bis_divider" data-title="<?php the_title();?>" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>">
      </div>        
<?php  ..
```

.....
....

Here is the initial setup and how nonce is created:

```
/**
          * Registers assets for frontend
         * */
         function bis_register_frontend_assets() {                 
            // Add some parameters for the JS.
           /**
              * Load the Javascript if found as a singluar post.
            */
        if (is_singular() && !in_category( array(15,26946,29186) ) ) {
              /**
             * Frontend Style 
             * */
             wp_enqueue_style('bis-frontend-css', BIS_CSS_DIR . 'frontend/frontend.css',false, BIS_VERSION);//registering animate.css
             /**
             * Frontend JS
             * */
              // echo get_template_directory_uri()/images/loader.gif
             wp_enqueue_script('bis-frontend-js', BIS_JS_DIR . 'frontend.js', array('jquery'), true, BIS_VERSION);//registering frontend js 
             $options = get_option( BIS_SETTINGS ); 
             global $post;
              // Variables for JS scripts
              wp_localize_script('bis-frontend-js', 'bis_frontend_js_params', array(
                'bbscroll_load_ajax_type'    => esc_attr($options['load_ajax_type']),
                'bbscroll_MainClass'         => esc_attr($options['appendElementClass']),
                'bbscroll_ajax_container'    => esc_attr($options['container_class']),
                'bbscroll_markup_type'       => esc_attr($options['markup_type']),
                'bbscroll_replace_url'       => intval($options['replace_url']),
                'bbscroll_ajaxurl'           => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                'bbscroll_loader_type'       => $options['bb_scroll_ajax_image'],
                'bbscroll_loader_img'        => esc_url($options['bb_scroll_ajax_image_url']),
                'bbscroll_default_loader'    => BIS_IMAGE_DIR. 'smart_scroll-ajax_loader.gif',
                'bbscroll_posts_limit'       => isset($options['post_limit'])?esc_attr($options['post_limit']):'',
                'bbscroll_category_options'  => $options['category_options'],
                'bbscroll_order_next_posts'  => $options['order_next_posts'],
                'bbscroll_post_link_target'  => $options['post_link_target'],
                'bbscroll_posts_featured_size'  => $options['posts_featured_size'],
                'bbscroll_postid'            => $post->ID,
                'bbscroll_ajax_nonce'        => wp_create_nonce('bis-ajax-nonce'),
              ));



            } // END if is_singular() && get_post_type()

         }
```

Comment: Have you considered abandoning admin AJAX for a superior/easier REST API endpoint?

Comment: Is admin ajax use not recommended? I am extending an available plugin. What are the other REST API endpoints available with Wordpress?

Comment: I personally recommend using the new REST API endpoints, it's just a lot easier with fewer caveats and traps to fall into. With Admin AJAX you have to do a lot of the security validation yourself, whereas the REST endpoints take care of that if you pass them the appropriate parameters. Besides, your question can't be answered from just the JS code, we'd need to see the PHP side of things, as well as how that nonce is being generated

Comment: Actually the important part is the AJAX function in the back-end, which you didn't include in your question.

Comment: @JackJohansson - did you mean the callback function?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant.

Comment: Updated the code with more details. Basically trying to customize an existing infinite scroll plugin.